# When to use 'advent' and 'arrival'?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

I wanted to know when to use the word advent and arrival in the sentence. Please provide examples and explanation for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: On its face, I'll accept that some research went into this question. Dictionaries won't necessarily make clear the nuanced differences. **advent** is usually understood to mean the  emergence of some thing bringing with it a major good or benefit: "With the advent of modern antibiotics...." whereas **arrival** is neutral, and could be used with good or bad. "With the arrival of smallpox in the New World..."  We probably wouldn't say "With the advent of plague..."

Comment: as often as we would say "with the arrival of plague"

Answer (score 0):

As nouns the difference between arrival and advent is that **arrival** is the act of arriving or something that has arrived while **advent** is coming; coming to; approach; arrival.

> 1. **Advent** - arrival that has been awaited (especially of something momentous)
>      
>      "the advent of the computer"
>      
>      
>      The season including the four Sundays preceding Christmas:
>
>    - church calendar, ecclesiastical calendar - a calendar of the Christian year indicating the dates of fasts and festivals
>    - season - a recurrent time marked by major holidays; "it was the Christmas season"
>    - Advent Sunday - the first of the four Sundays during Advent
> 2. **Arrival** -
>
>    - The act of arriving:
>        advent, appearance, coming.
>    - One that arrives:
>        comer, visitor.
>    - The achievement of something desired, planned, or attempted:
>        success, successfulness.